# How to start mysql database when program starts?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I created a program C# windows form which connects to xampp mysql database, so before I started to run the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and run the program I setup first the xampp control panel to start the apache and mysql and after doing that my program will connect to the database. But now I already finished my program and I don't want to do all the setup again and again every time I launch my program. Is that possible programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql and Apache should be installed as Windows services.  These can be configured to start automatically with Windows, or you could start them by calling `net start` from your application.  There may also be some classes in .Net that can handle service interaction, but I'm not familiar with them.  Check MSDN to be sure, though.